# Wordpress Plugin Settings

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to save the settings of a plugin I'm creating.

The basic functionality I'm trying to achieve is that, the plugin user can select a custom post type and in doing so it will return all of the field types of that post object.

Now, the above field types they can select which ones they would like to display i.e. If i had a product and I wanted to only see it's Price and Description, they could simply click the corresponding checkboxes and it would update other plugin functionality.

Currently, I'm using Javascript to create an array of the selected checkboxes which I then intended to save as a plugin option.

How can I get that array from Javascript to be passed as a Plugin Option (option.php) parameter and then be able to use it to populate the corresponding checkboxes based on the saved settings.

Here's a quick example of the settings page, incase my explanation wasn't clear.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ynwbs8bwj30g57n/before.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jg2th2wrfd964zp/after.png

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I did not do this in a long time so this might not be perfect, but here is a gist of my idea on solving your problem using AJAX (in jQuery- a JavaScript library).
Ajax will let you send a JSON string to a php function in your functions.php using hooks.

Firstly in your functions.php you need to localize the wp ajax script.

```
function add_ajax(){
     wp_localize_script( 'main-script', 'options', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_ajax');
```

Then you need to add an action hook, which starts with *wp_ajax_*. This hook is tied to a function that will handle your options and will be called inside a jQuery script.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_options', 'handle_options' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_options', 'handle_options' );  

function handle_options() {
      $options = $_POST['options'];
      //DO SOMETHING
      wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

After that you need to make an ajax call after your user chooses their options, which will convert your array into JSON and send use the action hook wp_ajax_options. Something like this:

```
var options = = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: output.ajax_url,
        data : {
           action : 'options',
           'options': options
        },
        success: function(response){
            //you can do something here with the response.
        }
    });
```

Definitely check these  resources for more:

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/

Comment: Hi @PeterTheLobster, thanks for the feedback!

I'm already doing a very similar thing to get the array from javascript to wordpress, my issue is then saving said array to the wp settings and being able to successfully retrieve it.

Comment: @Connor would this help you? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61431/efficient-way-of-saving-plugin-options

Comment: Thanks! That somewhat helped me, but i've tried to do this so many different ways, could you please outline the order in which I need to call each settings api function in order to simply get something to save? However, I seem to do it, it just doesn't work... I'm pretty new to Wordpress and despite seeming really straightforward I'm struggling to get my head around the settings api.